# what is the usage of ${var#something}?

Tags: shell

I'm looking at some shell script and I found something like

```
${var#*.}
```

if $var is 111.txt then

```
echo ${var#*.}
```

will return txt, which is good, I want to know why, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${var#pattern}` will find the pattern(starts at the beginning, the shortest) of the variable's value and delete it, then return the rest.
So, your pattern means "anything followed by a .", then you are left with a "txt".
By the way, `${var##pattern}` will delete the longest matching pattern
if `var=111.111.txt`, then
`${var#\*.}` will return `111.txt`
`${var##\*.}` will return `txt`

Comment: Say cloudygoose, is cloudyFan your alter ego? Answering and upvoting/accepting each others questions...? And then getting confused with the accounts, answering your own question and then deleting it once you realized your mistake? (stackoverflow.com/questions/16790751) Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`bash` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
${parameter#word}
```

> Remove matching prefix pattern.
>   The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. If the pattern matches the beginning of the  value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because the ability to manipulate parts of strings with patterns is jolly useful as it avoids expensive forks and pipes and

- The original Unix Shell did it that way
- It's [specified in the POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) as follows:

> `${#parameter}`
>
> String Length. The length in characters of the value of parameter
>   shall be substituted. If parameter is '*' or '@', the result of the
>   expansion is unspecified. If parameter is unset and set -u is in
>   effect, the expansion shall fail.
>
> The following four varieties of parameter expansion provide for
>   substring processing. In each case, pattern matching notation (see
>   Pattern Matching Notation), rather than regular expression notation,
>   shall be used to evaluate the patterns. If parameter is '#', '*', or
>   '@', the result of the expansion is unspecified. If parameter is unset
>   and set -u is in effect, the expansion shall fail. Enclosing the full
>   parameter expansion string in double-quotes shall not cause the
>   following four varieties of pattern characters to be quoted, whereas
>   quoting characters within the braces shall have this effect. In each
>   variety, if word is omitted, the empty pattern shall be used.
>
> `${parameter%[word]}`
>
> Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
>   a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
>   with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern
>   deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '%'.
>
> `${parameter%%[word]}`
>
> Remove Largest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
>
> `${parameter#[word]}`
>
> Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
>   a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
>   with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern
>   deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '#'.
>
> `${parameter##[word]}`
>
> Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.